# heads-up notification not showing on background or terminated state using Firebase Admin Sdk with Laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging to my Flutter mobile app with a plugin called flutter_local_notifications for showing heads-up notification in every state of the app. Everything is working fine until I created a Laravel project for sending notification to the specific device using device token.

I have integrated the Laravel project with Firebase Admin SDK and I follow the documentation for using Cloud Messaging. For now, the heads-up notification only showing in foreground state and not showing in background or terminated state.

Here is my testing laravel controller

```
public function sendFCM()
{
    $deviceToken = 'device token';

    $title = 'My Notification Title';
    $body = 'My Notification Body';
    $imageUrl = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/';

    $notification = Notification::fromArray([
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $body,
        'image' => $imageUrl,
    ]);

    $notification = Notification::create($title, $body);

    $data = ['route' => 'resultipt'];

    $message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $deviceToken)
        ->withNotification($notification)
        ->withData($data)
        ->withHighestPossiblePriority();

    try {
        $this->messaging->send($message);
        return response()->json(['status' => 'Successfully sent']);
    } catch (InvalidMessage $th) {
        return response()->json(['status' => $th->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own problem.

I forgot to add my notification channel id to the android config.

```
$deviceToken = 'device token here';

$title = "My Notification Title";
$body = "My Notification Body";
$channel_id = "channel id here";

$notification = Notification::fromArray([
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $body,
]);

$config = AndroidConfig::fromArray([
    'priority' => 'high',
    'notification' => [
        'channel_id' => $channel_id,
        'color' => '#42A5F5',
        'sound' => 'default',
    ],
]);

$notification = Notification::create($title, $body);

$data = ['route' => 'resultipt'];

$message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $deviceToken)
    ->withAndroidConfig($config)
    ->withNotification($notification)
    ->withData($data);

try {
    $this->messaging->send($message);
    return response()->json(['status' => 'Successfully sent', 'message' => $message]);
} catch (InvalidMessage $th) {
    return response()->json(['status' => $th->getMessage()]);
}
```